# PHP preg_match for A-Z,a-z,0-9, _,-, and one space

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have found a PHP preg match for A-Z,a-z,0-9, _,-, and one space. I am using it for username validation on my website. I will redirect if the preg_match is "not secure enough". I think the only character I need to worry about is the _ (underscore) from what I am reading up on. Does anyone know any SQL injection code I can run and test if this case is vulnerable? Or is this code sufficient for what I'm trying to achieve. PS - I will also be using prepared statements since this user input will be going to my database...

```
// escapes special characters
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
// checks to see if characters other than A-Z, a-z, 0-9, " "(white space), -(hyphen), and _ (underscore)...
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\040\_\-]+$/i', $username))
{
    echo 'secure';
}
else
{
    echo 'not secure';
}
```

Comment: `\w` is the equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: *"I will redirect if the preg_match is "not secure enough"."* - What do you mean by "not secure enough"? Are you afraid someone will hack you by using characters recognized as an injection?

Comment: I deleted my answer; your comment you left under it *"I am doing this strictly for only a username check against my database. My user is allowed to create their own password and I have it using the standard PHP hash and salt functions. But if they input those characters initially I am considering it at malicious and simply them to redirect back out and retype their username again."* doesn't support what you posted here and makes no sense. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: "I will also be using prepared statements..." - if you use prepared statements, you don't have to worry about sql injections...

Comment: @Philipp okay my user when they create the username is only allowed to use the preg_match I specified up above. Is there still any need for real_escape_string or should I just eliminate this as well?

Comment: you're still contradicting yourself ^

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner so what do you suggest that I do then?

Comment: use what I wrote in my answer and I'd have to undelete it in order for you to mark the question as answered, because that is what you should be doing instead.

Comment: Your answer is confusing to me would you care to clarify a few points? I have to check 2 fields within my database "username" and "password" meaning I will need to take these two string inputs into my database which is user input (aka dangerous).... The password verify is what I am already doing to check my password but I have no way of checking if my username is correct. I only hash my password not my usernames so they are stored as plain text. So my question is how do I make password_verify work for usernames if it was never hashed to begin with? @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: if you're wanting to check if a row matches or rows, then you need to either use `COUNT(col)` or `num_rows()`, if that's what you're asking. As for your *"how do I make password_verify work for usernames if it was never hashed to begin with?"* - You can't. You need to use the former part of my comment here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner lol hold on you are just thinking about my question ahead of what I am doing... I know how to do all this stuff you have mentioned. The reason I am asking this preg_match question is to prevent SQL injection from the user input before I use the input as string input in my prepared statement. I figured since I only wanted certain characters to even exist as potentially input I would filter them out before I started checking the database columns of "username" and "password"...

Comment: you don't need that function; as I said in my answer ;-) both `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` take injection into consideration and no need to escape passwords, it will work against you. A prepared statement is good for user input yes, but not for passwords when using those 2 functions. So I believe I understood your question from the start.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner okay from what I am understanding from what you are saying you are telling me to use the functions. In order to use these function I need to hash my username column?

Comment: why would you hash a username column? it's not worth it, really. But that's up to you but it won't help. See the new answer below, I have nothing else to add here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't limit passwords or check if there are any characters that you think will hack you. `preg_match()` isn't what you're looking for, believe me.

What you're doing now is by all means, not necessary.

By using  `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` (along with a prepared statement), will ensure that your database does not get compromised.

Let your users choose their own passwords and use the functions from the manuals on PHP.net shown below.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Passwords such as `--DELETE 123, '\<br>` are considered as being perfectly valid.

Both of those hashing functions are perfectly safe to be used and for any character. Nothing during transit will pose a security risk.

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` will have adverse effects on characters such as `\`.

I.e.: `abc\` will turn into `abc\\` with the slash being escaped.

So again, don't use what you're wanting to use now.

---

Read [Cleansing User Passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) (*here on Stack Overflow*) as it talks about how hashing passwords makes the data safe for storage without having to prepare.

Comment: I am doing this strictly for only a username check against my database. My user is allowed to create their own password and I have it using the standard PHP hash and salt functions. But if they input those characters initially I am considering it at malicious and simply them to redirect back out and retype their username again.

Comment: @hbennet3 I don't get what you're asking, sorry. I submitted this on what you posted.